# How to skip special characters encoding in Jersey responses

Tags: json, jersey, jax-rs, html-encode

I want to return a json that contains some strings. The problem is Jersey encodes some characters in these strings.

More specifically, it's turning `<`, `>`, `=`, `'` and `&` (html special characters) into `\\u003c`, `\\u003d`, `\\u003e`, etc. (unicode literals)

How do I make it leave these characters as they are?